# Call specific method on object depending on selected enum value

Tags: java, enums

Let's assume we have an enum, that represents searchable fields:

```java
enum SearchableFields {
    ALL,
    FIELD1,
    FIELD2,
    FIELD3;
}
```

This enum is displayed via a (combobox) selection inside a GUI. At runtime, I want to evaluate the selection of this combobox and search accordingly.

Depending on the selection, I need to retrieve the fields to search from a POJO (example below) via a getter.

```java
class FieldPojo {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    ...
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }
    ...
}
```

I currently use a `switch` statement to evaluate the selection of `SelectableFields` and to then retrieve the correct field(s) to search:

```java
private String retrieveField(FieldPojo f) {
    switch (selectedField) {
    case ALL:
        return retrieveAll(); // method that retrieves all available fields
    case FIELD1:
        return f.getField1();
    ...
}
```

This does work, however I feel like it's clunky.

**Question:**

Is there a more concise way to do this without evaluating the `enum` via a `switch`? (Java 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a reference to the getter in your enum constants:

```java
enum SearchableFields {
    ALL(FieldPojo::retrieveAll),
    FIELD1(FieldPojo::getField1)

    private final Function<FieldPojo, String> accessor;
    SearchableFields(Function<FieldPojo, String> acccessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public String get(FieldPojo fp) {
        return accessor.apply(fp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static map instead of the switch-case.

```
private static final Map<SearchableFields,Supplier<String>> searchableFieldsToFieldPojo = Map.of(
    ALL, this::retrieveAll,
    FIELD1, FieldPojo::retrieveAll
    );
```

And then you can access via:

```
searchableFieldsToFieldPojo.get(selectedField).get();
```

Comment: It would probably be `Function<? super FieldPojo, String>`

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can modify all parts of the code, you have several options:

- Put the `retrieveField` into the class `FieldPojo` and modify it's parameter so it takes the enum `SearchableFields` as parameter.
- Put the fields of `FieldPojo` as values into a map with a key of type `SearchableFields`. You can then decide whether you want to have "ALL" as an extra entry of the map or handle it as special case in a method similar to `retrieveField`. You could use this to have a "default" handling if you want to update the enum but not the `FieldPojo` class.
- You put `retrieveField` into the class `FieldPojo` together with the `SearchableFields` enum - since only `FieldPojo` knows, which fields it actually provides as searchable fields.
- You use introspection to gather the list of possible searchable fields and also access their contents.

Depending on your real requirements (you only showed a very abstract and specific version of them) one or the other method might be "the right one" for you. I would actually prefer the "everything into `FieldPojo`" as the most robust one, but on the other hand if you are not able to change `FieldPojo` and have to handle many different classes like it, the introspection variant might be the right one. (Be aware that it is fragile in terms of security and also probably very slow.)

Answer (score 0):

Enums can contain method definitions, so one way is to define the method that retrieves the field name based on the enum value. I assume you have the actual field name stored as a member field also. Then you can override the method for the special `ALL` value:

```
enum SearchableFields {
    ALL("all") { // all is just a placeholder in this case
        @Override
        String retrieveField(FieldPojo f) {
            // logic for all fields
        }
    },
    FIELD1("field1"),
    FIELD2("field2"),
    FIELD3("field3");
    
    SearchableFields(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = Optional.of(fieldName);
    }
    SearchableFields() {
        fieldName = Optional.empty();
    }
    private final Optional<String> fieldName;

    String retrieveField(FieldPojo f) {
        if (fieldName.isPresent()) {
            return (String) f.getClass().getField(fieldName.get()).get(f);
        } else {
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```